Summing Multiple fields in a filtered list
I have a similar problem but I'd like to to sum up two fields instead of one (profit in the above example). let me explain:-
Here I'm defining the my array
struct DailyContractorsSummary : Identifiable, Hashable
{
    var id = UUID()
    var rigOperator: String
    var lostTime: Int
    var oPTime: Int
    var efficiency: Double
    var animate: Bool = false
}

I use the following to sum up oPTime
let filteredDailyContractorsSummary = Dictionary(grouping: Variables.dailyContractorsSummary) { element in
                                            element.rigOperator
                                        }.mapValues { recordsGroupedByRigOperator -> Int in
                                            recordsGroupedByRigOperator
                                                .map { ($0.oPTime) }
                                                .reduce(0, +)
                                        }.map { dailySummary in
                                            FilteredDailyContractorsOPTime(rigOperator: dailySummary.key, oPTime: dailySummary.value, efficiency: 0)
                                        }

I want to be able to sum up oPTime and lostTime. I can only successfully do it with oPTime or lostTime but not both together. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance
I want to be able to sum up oPTime and lostTime. I can only successfully do it with oPTime or lostTime but not both together. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance

Your current code gives you a result of type [FilteredDailyContractorsOPTime]. What type of result do you want by summing both opTime and lostTime?

I would like to be able to give the result of type DailyContractorsSummary, but I can't define it in the result without giving a value for lostTime, and to be able to do so I want to map the sum of it. Eventually, I want the sum of oPTime and the sum of lostTime

In this code, only the sum of oPTime can be calculated. Is there a way to add lostTime here .map { ($0.oPTime) }.reduce(0, +)?

The mapValues closure can return a tuple (Int, Int). The first element is the sum of opTime and the second element is the sum of lostTime.
let filteredDailyContractorsSummary = Dictionary(
        grouping: dailyContractorsSummary, by: \.rigOperator
    )
    .mapValues { recordsGroupedByRigOperator -> (Int, Int) in
        recordsGroupedByRigOperator
            .map { ($0.oPTime, $0.lostTime) }
            .reduce((0, 0)) { ($0.0 + $1.0, $0.1 + $1.1) }
    }

The expression ($0.0 + $1.0, $0.1 + $1.1) is quite hard to read, but all its doing is adding two tuples ($0 and $1) together, element by element.
It might help to write a function like this:
func +(lhs: (Int, Int), rhs: (Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int) {
    (lhs.0 + rhs.0, lhs.1 + rhs.1)
}

Note that you can generalise this to any tuple arity and type, but this crashes the compiler in 5.10. It works in Swift 6 though.
func +<each T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: (repeat each T), rhs: (repeat each T)) -> (repeat each T) {
    (repeat ((each lhs) + (each rhs)))
}

Then you can write .reduce((0, 0), +).
It seems like you want to map the groups back to an array of DailyContractorsSummarys, so you can add this at the end:
.map { key, value in
    DailyContractorsSummary(rigOperator: key, lostTime: value.0, oPTime: value.1, efficiency: 0)
}


AAAAAH PERFECT! Thank you soooo much, that did the trick. Most appreciated!
